# wowza webrtc our own voice and feedback or echo

Tags: audio, webrtc, wowza

We have deployed webrtc on wowza.  However, we are getting our own voice back. Could be feedback or echo?

Comment: Please improve this answer with a better description of the scenario.  In this particular case, you are likely just hearing your test produce this problem by having open microphones.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, there is currently no method in wowza to battle echo. However, you can install extra layers of audio filtering - for example, [this article](http://solicall.com/echo-cancellation-with-flash-a-case-study/) shows how to use PBXMate for echo cancellation. In case this link becomes invalid, full requirements are following:

- The Flashphoner Client is a flash based client. It could be replaced by other flash based clients.
- The Wowza server is a standard streaming server.
- The Flashphoner is responsible for translating the protocol of the streaming data to the standard SIP protocol.
- The Elastix server is a well known unified communication server.
- The PBXMate is an Elastix AddOn for audio filtering.